# Firebase project using corporate GSuite account

Tags: firebase, google-workspace

I am planning to purchase a [Business G Suite Account](https://gsuite.google.com/pricing.html) from Google but I am now wondering if I will be able to use it in **Firebase** in order to be able to create **Firebase projects**

[image]

I know Firebase has been Google's platform since 2014 or so but I am just curious before purchasing. Is there gonna be any kind of restrictions? Because, I won't be using accounts like somebody@**gmail**.com but rather somebody@**mycompany**.com